# How to fix ggplot double y axis in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph with two y axis. I know there are a lot of other questions out there similar to this but I just cant seem to figure it out based on other posts

So the issue I am having is the y axis scale. Here is what I am doing

```
Time <- c("June-2018-30", "July-2018-31", "August-2018-31", "September-2018-30",
            "October-2018-31", "November-2018-30", "December-2018-31", "January-2019-31", 
            "February-2019-28", "March-2019-31", "April-2019-30", "May-2019-31")

Bitcoin <- c(3.469861e-17, 3.188903e-17, 2.685114e-17, 2.42335e-17, 2.322641e-17, 
              2.447058e-17, 3.18029e-17, 2.944836e-17, 2.839419e-17, 2.76008e-17, 
              2.661607e-17, 2.536966e-17)

`USD Return` <- c(2.35e-13, 2.27e-13, 1.80e-13, 1.60e-13, 1.51e-13, 1.33e-13, 1.18e-13, 
                  1.08e-13, 1.047e-13, 1.09e-13, 1.37e-13, 1.83e-13)

total.values3 <- data.frame(Time, Bitcoin,`USD Return`, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=total.values3, aes(x=Time, y=`USD Return`, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `USD Return`), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Bitcoin), color = "red") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous("USD Return", 
                      sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10000, name = "Bitcoin Return")) + 
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%B-%Y-%d"), 
               date_labels = "%B-%Y", breaks = total.values3$Time)
```

Here is a picture of what output

[image]

I am not sure what is going wrong. I can see that the scale is wrong. I can't figure out why the bitcoin line is just a straight line. I also don't know why the y axis on the right side goes into the negative

Comment: first of all get rid of  ```y=`USD Return` ``` in the `ggplot` and just keep it in the `geom`.

Comment: I did that but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: The bitcoin line is a straight line because the geoms follow the left-hand axis's numbers. If you want the bitcoin line to follow the right-hand axis, you need to do to it the reverse of the transformation you put on the RH axis.

Comment: See I figured that was the issue. I just can figure out how to flip them. It keeps putting the USD Return on the left side. I have tried switching the order but it only seems to pick the USD Return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total.values3$Time <- as.Date(total.values3$Time, format = "%B-%Y-%d")

ggplot(data=total.values3, aes(x=Time, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `USD Return`), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Bitcoin*10000), color = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous("USD Return", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10000, name = "Bitcoin Return")) + 
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%B-%Y-%d"), 
                      date_labels = "%B-%Y", breaks = total.values3$Time)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: if the line I added doesn't help, feel free to rollback.